# Combine multiprocess and multithread in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

(I don't know if this should be asked here at SO, or one of the other stackexchange)

When doing heav I/O bound tasks e.g API-calls or database fetching, I wonder, if Python only uses one process for multithreading, i.e can we create even more threads by combining multiprocessing and multithreading, like the pseudo-code below

```py
for process in Processes:
    for thread in threads:
        fetch_api_resuls(thread)
```

or does Python do this automatically?

Comment: Could you give an example of why that is useful in the first place? I mean the limiting factor is likely your hardware, in the sense of how many processors you have available.

Comment: When doing I/O bound tasks. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there would be any point doing this: spinning up a new *process* has a relatively high cost, and spinning up a new *thread* has a pretty high cost.  Serialising tasks to those threads or processes costs again, and synchronising state costs...again.

What I *would* do if I had two sets of problems:

- I/O bound problems (e.g. fetching data over a network)
- CPU bound problems related to those I/O bound problems

is to combine multi*processing* with asyncio.  This has a much lower overhead---we only have *one* thread, and we pay for the scheduler only (but no serialisation), doesn't involve spinning up a gazillion processes (each of which uses around as much virtual memory as the parent process) or threads (each of which still uses a fair chunk of memory).

However, I would not use asyncio within the multiprocessing threads---I'd use asyncio in the *main* thread, and offload cpu-intensive tasks to a pool of worker threads when needed.

I suspect you probably *can* use threading inside multiprocessing, but it is very unlikely to bring you any speed boost.